# Contacts view not updating from contacts/new view using the mail_form gem in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, contacts, contact-form

I am working with the mail_form gem. I have already created an specific controller for the contact form and everythink seems right but when I submit any form the view does´nt change from the create one to the create one but the url does. It shows the localhost3000/gmm/contacts(which has changed from localhost3000/gmm/contacts/new). I am worried about this issue; Moreover, the new view shows the e-mail in the name´s field as showed in the image:

"http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-Q4qUs1CHm-M/Voqc-VYiXII/AAAAAAAAAdE/nJMxgpTEu5s/s320/problem1.jpg"

```
    Controller file:

        class ContactsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @contact = Contact.new
end

def create
    @contact=Contact.new(params[:contact])
    @contact.request=request
    if @contact.deliver
        flash.now[:error]=nil
    else
        flash.now[:error]='Cannot send message.'
        render :new
    end
end
```

end

New view:

```
      <body>
<section>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 text-center">
                <h2 class="margin-top-0 wow fadeIn">Get in Touch</h2>
                <hr class="primary">
                <p>We love feedback. Fill out the form below and we'll get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <%= form_for @contact do |f| %>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-faded">
                    <%= f.label :name %>
                    <%= f.text_field :name, required: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Name"%>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 text-faded">
                    <%= f.label :email %>
                    <%= f.email_field :name, required: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Email" %>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 text-faded">
                    <%= f.label :message %>
                    <%= f.text_area :message, as: :text, :class => "form-control", :rows=>"9", :placeholder => "Your message here.."%>
                </div>
                <div class="hidden">
                    <%= f.label :nickname %><br>
                    <%= f.text_field :nickname, hint:"leave this field blank"%>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                    <%= f.submit "Send Message", :class=> "btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg" %>
                </div>
                <%end%>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Model:

```
         class Contact<MailForm::Base
attribute :name,    :validate => true
attribute :email,   :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
attribute :message, :validate => true
attribute :nickname,:captcha => true

def headers
    {
    :subject => "Contact Form",
    :to => "kurtco_91@hotmail.com",
    :to => "yomi.89gm@gmail.com",
    :from => %("#{name}" <#email>)
    }
end
```

end

Routes:

```
      Rails.application.routes.draw do

           resources :contacts, only: [:new,:create]

          get 'gmm/home' 

          get 'gmm/about'

          get 'gmm/services'

          get 'gmm/contact'

          get '/change_locale/:locale', to: 'settings#change_locale', as: :change_locale
```

I think it must be a problem with the post verb or my routing but I did rake: routes several times and no progress. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to Email showing in name field is you are actually saving email into name field.

change email field from this:

```
<%= f.email_field :name, required: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Email" %>
```

to this:

```
<%= f.email_field :email, required: true, :class => "form-control", :placeholder => "Email" %>
```

Answer to URL issue is:

in your controller after according to my assessment you should save the contact if u need. if contact save successfully you should redirect to new_contact_path.

controller should look like this:

```
def create
@contact=Contact.new(params[:contact])
@contact.request=request
if @contact.deliver
    flash.now[:error]=nil
else
    flash.now[:error]='Cannot send message.'
    redirect_to new_contact_path
end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot I am a bit sleepy I have changed the :name to:email and now it works. Thanks :)